# JCR SQL2 Query comparing name and path with like

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr, jcr-sql2

I was trying to execute following jcr sql2 query:

```
        String expression = "SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS p " +
            "WHERE  NAME(p) like 'opony.txt'";
```

But I got

```
javax.jcr.UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException.
```

Is it any other way to search for nodes that names are like '%example%'?

I was also trying to search for nodes with specified path

```
        String expression = "SELECT * FROM [nt:base] " +
            "WHERE PATH([nt:base]) like '/a/b'";
```

But I got

```
javax.jcr.query.InvalidQueryException: Query:
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE PATH([(*)nt:base]) like '/a/b'; expected: LENGTH, NAME, LOCALNAME, SCORE, LOWER, UPPER, or CAST
```

How can I search nodes that paths are like '%example%'?

I am using JCR_SQL2

```
javax.jcr.query.Query query = queryManager.createQuery(expression, Query.JCR_SQL2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

A couple of points:

- If you don't include a wildcard like '%" in your pattern, there's not much difference between LIKE and the ordinary = operator.
- PATH() and NAME() are not supported in all implementations of SQL2.  They appear to be OK under JBoss.
- To search for nodes within a subtree, use the ISDESCENDANTNODE() function.
- There is a [jcr:title] attribute that you can test; it's not the same as the node name, but it might serve your purposes.

So, for your first query, try something like

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS p WHERE [jcr:title] like '%opony%'
    and ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/a/b')
```

The [JBoss documentation on querying](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossdna/0.7/manuals/reference/html/jcr-query-and-search.html) is fairly good, but be aware that it may not line up exactly with vanilla Jackrabbit.  I've also used this [cheat sheet](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/JCR+Query+Cheat+Sheet) for the Magnolia implementation.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't the query use "... WHERE [jcr:name] LIKE ..."?

Comment: Yes, except that JCR doesn't use that attribute name.  My answer is sort of scrambled.  I will try to clean it up.

Comment: Well, if I didn't need '%' in my pattern I wouldn't ask for like, I thought it was obvious. NAME() works with '=', so I guess it must be implemented.

Comment: Unfortunately your query doesn't find files which names are like '%opony%'.